# Cannot access mysql in local database

Tags: windows, networking, mysql, home-networking, localhost

I wroted python app which connect to mysql database (`192.168.1.19 ubuntu`) in my local network and make query.

I tested my app on my computer (`192.168.1.3 windows 10`) and everything works properly. But when I run app on other pc (`192.168.1.2 windows 10`) it tries to connect to `192.168.1.2` not to `*.1.19`! `Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.2' (using password: YES)`.

This computer (`*.1.2`) has normal access to `*.1.19` for example in web browser.

In application I declared access data to ip `192.168.1.19` not to some host like localhost.

Where should I looking for that error? Some routing? System restrictions?

Comment: Usually MySQL allows remote connection if the IP already exist in the Grant permission group. You can ensure this by executing the below queries,  use mysql;  select USER, HOST from user;   If your IP is not in the  query result then you should  add your IP address from where you are connecting.

Comment: Eh.. newbie mistake. I haven't added that IP. Thank you for your help.